# appium+android+windows --- wait not working ["dumpWindowHierarchy"]

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Appium is running fast and I am not able to execute the wait command, please check the below log of appium, I am using the following wait , thanks for your help in advance.

`public static void waitForVisible(final By by, int waitTime) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT);
          for (int attempt = 0; attempt < waitTime; attempt++) {
            try {
            driver.findElement(by);
                break;
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        }
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
      }`

> debug: transferPageSourceXML command: "D..\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 pull /data/local/tmp/dump.xml "D..\Local\Temp\1-6552-8k.xml"
>   debug: Responding to client with error: {"status":7,"value":{"message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."},"sessionId":"a6be962d-1b18-4447-9e62-511a3d1ca51a"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/a6be962d-1b18-4447-9e62-511a3d1ca51a/element 500 2128.246 ms - 164 
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/a6be962d-1b18-4447-9e62-511a3d1ca51a/timeouts/implicit_wait {"ms":1000}
>   debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/a6be962d-1b18-4447-9e62-511a3d1ca51a/timeouts/implicit_wait
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/a6be962d-1b18-4447-9e62-511a3d1ca51a/timeouts/implicit_wait 200 2.684 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"a6be962d-1b18-4447-9e62-511a3d1ca51a"}
>   debug: Request received with params: {"ms":1000}
>   debug: Set Android implicit wait to 1000ms
>   debug: Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"a6be962d-1b18-4447-9e62-511a3d1ca51a"}
>   debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/a6be962d-1b18-4447-9e62-511a3d1ca51a/element
>   debug: Request received with params: {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.widget.FrameLayout[0]/android.widget.LinearLayout[0]/android.widget.FrameLayout[0]/android.widget.LinearLayout[0]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[0]/android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Home')]"}
>   debug: Pushing command to appium work queue: ["dumpWindowHierarchy"]
>   debug: [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"dumpWindowHierarchy","params":{}}
>   debug: [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   debug: [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: dumpWindowHierarchy
>   debug: [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(devicedriver, timeoutInSeconds);
Thread.sleep(3000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name(elementName)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command, e.g. for 5 seconds of waiting:

```
driver.wait(5)
```